# determing the probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have 2 sets of elements, say $A=\{a\}$ (only 1 element) and $B = \{b_1, b_2,..., b_n\}$.

The probability of picking $A$ is $0.3$ and the probability of picking $B$ is $0.7$, and all elements in $B$ have equal chances.

Now combining everything together:

What would be the probability of picking $a$ and the probability of picking any element in $B$.

Am I right to say:

$P(a)$ = 0.3

$P(\text{picking any element in}~B) = \frac{0.7}{n}$ ?

Comment: Your answer is OK.

Comment: wouldn't that reduce chances of B elements, taking into consideration that set B has higher probability?

Comment: If one or both answers resolve your question, then please click to accept one of them. Then this question will drop off our queue of ones without a useful answer. (If you keep using the site, you will eventually be able to do up-votes also.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to look at it is through conditional probabilities. If you have $P(A)=0.3$, $P(B)=0.7$ and $P(b_i \mid B)=1/n$ then by law of total probability
\begin{align}
P(b_i) &= P(b_i \mid B)P(B) + P(b_i \mid A)P(A)\\
&= \frac{1}{n}0.7 + 0
\end{align}
(using that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint) and
\begin{align}
P(a) &= P(a \mid B)P(B) + P(a \mid A)P(A)\\
&= 0+1 \cdot0.3
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're just starting probability. You are correct ---
and some of the comments here might be confusing. So here is the
full story in what I hope is the notation of your text. Sorry if this is redundant.

The probability assignment to the $n+1$ points in the sample space
is as follows:
$P(\{a\}) = .3,$ and $P(\{b_i\}) = .7/n,$ for $i = 1,\dots, n.$

Thus $P(A) = 0.3,$ where $A = \{a\},$ and
$P(B) = 0.7,$ where $B =\{b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n\}.$